# Application start error after migrating to websphere 9 from wabsphere 8.8.5

Tags: websphere, cdi, websphere-9

I am working on migrating my application to WAS 9.0 from WAS 8.5.5. Initially I was getting com.sun.faces.taglib classNotFound Exception. I added jsf jars to avoid this error. Now when I am trying to start the application I am getting below error.

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)
```

Unable to think of the next step. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)

[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:809)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1421)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2232)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5488)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5614)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:271 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1311)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:608)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:272 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1386)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:195)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:273 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:970)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:517)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:338)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:961)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:294)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[11/7/19 13:35:03:274 EST] 00000088 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application includes `javax.validation.Validator` either directly in the application artifacts or via a referenced shared library. The WebSphere runtime loads its own version of `Validator` and your application could be loading a different version (or the same version on in a different classloader). This scenario could cause the error you are seeing:

> "WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator"

I know you mentioned adding your own JSF jars, so maybe an implementation of Bean Validation got pulled in as well. If you can identify a version of the `javax.validation.*` classes being included in your application try removing them and rely on WebSphere to provide them.

See the following Liberty APAR that outlines this type of problem:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI71667